# Assigning a variable to an array in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a 1x4 matrix assigned to a variable BMI

```
BMI = [0.09 0.16 0.42 0.39];
```

How do i assign this variable BMI  to an array in SAS ? I tried this below , it didn't work,

```
array prob (4) BMI ;
```

I did that and got an error " Too few variables defined for the dimension(s) specified for the array prob". I know this works,

```
 array prob(4) (0.09, 0.16, 0.42, 0.39);
```

but i am interested in assigning a variable directly to an array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `array prob[4] (0.09, 0.16, 0.42, 0.39);` - the size of the array should be declare with `[ ]` instead of `( )`

Comment: Sky, I know it works with array prob[4] (0.09, 0.16, 0.42, 0.39);        I want to pass a matrix variable directly like this                array prob[4] BMI;                                                       Instead of array prob[4] (0.09, 0.16, 0.42, 0.39);

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you mean now. You're declaring an array size of 4 but initializing with only one variable. That's is the problem for "Too few variables defined for the dimension(s) specified for the array prob". This is probably what you looking for then - `array prob[*] BMI;`

Comment: Since you declare the size to be 4, you need at least 4 variable to initialize it e.g. `array prob[4] BMI BMI1 BMI2 BMI3;`, but if you only have one variable use `array prob[1] BMI` but array size of 1 will defeat the purpose of using array I guess. However if you're unsure of the number of variable you want to assign, use `[*]` for the size declaration

Comment: Sky, that problem is solved but it created a different problem (error). I am actually using the array prob[star] inside this function    Column1 = rand("Table", of prob[*]);  and this shows an error " Argument 2 to function RAND('Table',.) at line 647 column 15 is
invalid. "

Comment: It should be `Column1 = rand("Table", of prob[1]);` if you have only 1 variable BMI to reference to. If you have different arrays you might need to use loop to get the different output.

Comment: e.g. `array prob[*] BMI BMI2 BMI3 BMI4 BMI5;` then `prob[1]` will be `BMI` matrix, `prob[2]` will be `BMI2` matrix, ... and `prob[5]` will be `BMI5` matrix value.

Comment: sky what is your email id, i want to take this conversation offline if thats okay with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign it 'directly' the way you suggest, but you can certainly do it without too much effort.

```
data want;
set have;
array prob[4];
do _i = 1 to dim(prob);
  prob[_i] = scan(BMI,_i);
end;
run;
```

That iterates over the values of BMI (scan splits by space by default) and assigns them to the array elements.